# Footer buttons fixed?

Tags: html, css, button, fixed

I have 3 buttons that I need to stay fixed in the lower right corner of the page.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rQLDZ/)**.

But when I set `position:fixed` , it goes straight up to the top (which is also fixed).

How can I make them stay down there, yet when I scroll up to follow me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` ,and remove the `top:0;`,the bottom property sets the bottom edge of an element.

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/Fvn7J/1/)**

```
#buton{text-align:right;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    }
```

Comment: somehow better, it follows the scroll, but it's not positioned in the corner.

Comment: Manoj, it was good, but they're fixed on the <hr/>. How can I make them go lower?

Comment: almost perfect but i'll deal with it (the buttons are a bit far away from the <hr/). thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove

`top:0`

and set

`bottom:0; position: fixed; right: 0;`

```
#buton {
text-align: right;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

[See Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rQLDZ/3/)

Comment: still not positioned in the corner. if i keep the windown maximized it overlapses over a table i have in there. it goes above <hr/>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `top:0;` Since you need the buttons to stay fixed in the lower right corner of the page you should use `bottom: 0;position: fixed;`

Update the below part

```
    #buton{
    text-align:right;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    }
```

to the one given below,

```
   #buton{
   text-align:right;
   height: 100px;
   bottom:0;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 100;
  }
```

It will work like a charm.

Have made some changes, see the demo..

UPDATE :
[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bx8Av/)

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap everything in a `container` and give it position `relative`
- make `#buton` `absolute` with `bottom:0`
- keep `myButton` independent of any position

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fvn7J/2/)

```
html,body{
    height:100%; /* important */
}
#conatiner {
    position: relative;/* added*/
    height:100%;/* important */
}
#buton {
    text-align:right;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;/* added*/
    bottom: 0;
}
```